# How can differentiating a scalar like potential energy functions give a vector like field strength functions?

Tags: forces, potential-energy, calculus

Just wondering if anyone had a good explanation of how differentiating a scalar can give rise to a vector quantity.

Comment: [Wikipedia:Gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) gives a good explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal differentiation does not, because it preserves dimensionality. If I differentiate a scalar, it stays a scalar, if I differentiate a vector, it stays a vector. 
But, I can define a new operator, that transforms scalars into vectors and vice versa.

Let $\vec{\nabla}$ (read: nabla) be a new differential operator, that is defined as follows:

$$\vec{\nabla} = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\\\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\\\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, we can throw this on a few different objects and see what happens!

Let $s(x,y,z)$ be a scalar and $\vec{v}(x,y,z)$ be a vector, then:

$$\vec{\nabla}s = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}\\\frac{\partial s}{\partial y}\\\frac{\partial s}{\partial z}\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{v} = \frac{\partial v_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v_y}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial z}$$

Further readings:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del

Answer (score 0):

It is called a gradient and it applies to multi-variables scalar functions. Suppose you have a function $\psi(x,y,z)$, where $(x,y,z)$ are the cartesian coordinates then the gradient $\nabla$ of that function is defined as
$$
\nabla \psi(x,y,z) = \pmatrix{\partial_{x}\psi(x,y,z)\\\partial_{y}\psi(x,y,z)\\\partial_{z}\psi(x,y,z)},
$$
with $\partial_{x}$ the partial derivative operator. If the function is a single variable function, then the gradient is just the usual derivative and gives a scalar and not a vector.